# Dont have any idea about this username and password

Tags: mailgun

Authentication Required

The server http://api.mailgun.net:443 requires a username and password....

I am new in mailgun, and I dont understand that where I can find those username and password.

Can any one help me please ???

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because this is not mailgun support.

Comment: @subhobakshi Have you tried this API reference: https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/203380100-Where-can-I-find-my-API-key-and-SMTP-credentials-

Comment: Ok.... Ed can you help me about one more thing ??

Comment: IsabelHm can you help me about one more thing... ????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really isn't an appropriate question, but ...

"When you sign up for an account, you are given an API key. You authenticate to the Mailgun API by providing your API key in the request. You can manage your API key in the ‘My Account’ tab of the Control Panel.

Authentication to the API occurs via HTTP Basic Auth. Use api as the user name and your API key is the password."

https://documentation.mailgun.com/api-intro.html#authentication

Comment: @mrcheshire can you please look into this question please  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32418100/how-to-get-the-mailgun-bounce-list